# Variable types in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

I have a model with several variable types.

- boolean flag: 0 or 1
- positive float value: strictly greater than zero and known max  < 1000
- integer:  1 < value < 12
- categorical input: "AA","AB",.., "ZZ" - only about 100 values are observed
- Integer score as output value

  cvs file looks like

  "bool","pos_float","int_val","category_name","output_score"
  0,1.234,9,"CD",2
  1,6.836,5,"KF",6
  0,903.836,10,"AZ",4
  .....

  ```
  import tensorflow as tf
  import pandas as pd
  from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

  training_data_df = pd.read_csv("data_training.csv", dtype=float)

  X_training = training_data_df.drop('output_score', axis=1).values
  Y_training = training_data_df[['output_score']].values

  test_data_df = pd.read_csv("data_test.csv", dtype=float)

  X_testing = test_data_df.drop('output_score', axis=1).values
  Y_testing = test_data_df[['output_score']].values

  X_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
  Y_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

  X_scaled_training = X_scaler.fit_transform(X_training)
  Y_scaled_training = Y_scaler.fit_transform(Y_training)

  X_scaled_testing = X_scaler.transform(X_testing)
  Y_scaled_testing = Y_scaler.transform(Y_testing)
  ```

  Code above treats each variable as float and scales variables to (0,1). How to tell tensorflow that a variable is an integer? How to treat categorical variables?

Answer (score 1):

For the categorical variables, you're going to need to transform them into a numeric representation, either by a one-hot encoding (https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f) or via a hashing trick (https://medium.com/value-stream-design/introducing-one-of-the-best-hacks-in-machine-learning-the-hashing-trick-bf6a9c8af18f).

Essentially, you need to transform those strings into 1/0 boolean values for each feature category.

However, certain model, such as tree-based models like Random Forests and Gradient Boosted Trees, CAN handle multiple categories, so they simply need to be converted to a numeric-category type (you can retain the string values as labels).